# Rails routes logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it OK to put custom logic in routes.rb?

For example:

```
unless current_user
  root :to => anonymous_page
else
  root :to => logged_in_page
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* put custom logic into routes... but as avenger suggested - "current_user" won't work due to when the routes file is loaded. We sometimes use logic in our routefile (eg setting up routes that are only available if RAILS_ENV == 'development').

What you probably want is a before_filter on "anonymous_page" eg:

```
before_filter :redirect_if_logged_in, :only => :anonymous_page

def redirect_if_logged_in
  redirect_to logged_in_page if current_user.present?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work like that. Routes are read / created at server startup, not on per request basis. Such logic you have to put into controllers.

Comment: Note: that devise does something to make magic happen here:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-a-different-root-route-for-logged-in-out-users

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearance gem to do what you're thinking. From the clearance documentation:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedIn.new { |user| user.admin? } do
    root to: 'admin'
  end

  constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedIn.new do
    root to: 'dashboard'
  end

  constraints Clearance::Constraints::SignedOut.new do
    root to: 'marketing'
  end
end
```

This works because clearance adds itself into the middleware stack, making signed in status available before routes are processed.